# Understanding 2D array with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can someone please help me understand the last line in this snippet of code? I don't understand how that dynamically allocates the 2D array. I understand that on line 6, it's creating a pointer named 'a' and pointing it to an array of integers of size 5 as defined by 'c'.

What I don't understand is how that "new int" statement works with the r thrown into the equation. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
const int c = 5; //num of columns

 int main () {
   int r = 5;
   int (*a)[c];
   a = new int[r][c]; // allocate array
}
```

Comment: The last clause of your first paragraph is wrong. `a` is declared to be a pointer to an array of 5 `int`; *that's it*. it isn't pointing *to anything* (yet). That's what the `new []` is for.

Comment: A 2D array is a pointer to an array of pointers which each one points to another array (of ints in your case).

Comment: You forgot the semi-colon after `int r=5`

Comment: @Ripi2 No it is not.  A 2d array(`int[][]`) is an array of arrays which is very different from a `int**`

Comment: `int b[2][5]`  Then `int** pB = b` is an error but `int (*pb)[5] = b` is not. That's why I said "a pointer (b) to an array of pointers (pb)".

Comment: @NonCreature0714 fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a type `T` and are going to allocate an array of size `N` then this expression

```
new T[N]
```

returns the address of the type `T *` of the first element of the allocated array.

So you should write

```
T *a = new T[N];
```

For example if `T` is equivalent to the type int

```
typedef int T;
```

or

```
using T = int;
```

then the above allocation can be written

```
int *a = new int[N];
```

the size of element of the array is equal to `sizeof( int )` and usually is 4 bytes.

Now let's assume that you are going to allocate an array of elements of type `int[M]` where `M` is a constant integer expression.

You can write

```
typedef int T[M];
```

or

```
using T = int[M];
```

and

```
T *a = new T[N];
```

So you allocated an array of `N` elements where each element has size `sizeof( int[M]` and the pointer `a` points to the first element of the array.

Because `T` is equivalent tp `int [M]` you can write

```
int ( *a )[M] = new int [N][M];
```

that is this statement allocates an array of `N` elements of the type `int[M]` and the pointer `a` gets the address of the first element of the allocated array.

Returning to your program example

int r = 5
   int (*a)[c];
   a = new int[r][c];

you can rewrite it the following way

```
typedef int T[c];
```

or

```
using T = int[c];
```

and

```
T *a = new T[r];
```

that is this statements allocates an array of `r` elements (objects) of type `int[c]` and `a` is pointer to the first element of the allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

You're just making a pointer to a one-dimensional array, which requires two indexes to access elements. Nothing crazy, not quite undefined behavior, but not good either.

```
#include <iostream>
const int c = 5; //num of columns

int main () {
    int r = 5;

    //Creates a pointer to an array of 5 integer pointers.
    int (*a)[c];

    a = new int[r][c]; // allocate array

    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Displaying deferenced, unallocated array." << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<c;++i){
        std::cout << *a[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Diplaying pointers in the array." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Note how it's not a 2d array." << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<c;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<r;++j){
            std::cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << "Allocating array 1d, 1d style fails..." << std::endl;
    /*
    for(int i=0;i<c;++i){
        a[i] = 23; //Syntax error! Requires two indexes.
    }
    */

    std::cout << "Allocating 1d array 2d style... success!?" << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<r;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<c;++j){
            a[i][j] = 13;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Displaying allocated array." << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<r;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<c;++j){
            std::cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    delete [] a;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0x100202ba0
0x100202ba0

Displaying deferenced, unallocated array.
0
0
0
0
0
Diplaying pointers in the array.
Note how it's not a 2d array.
0x100202ba0 0x100202ba0 0x100202ba0 0x100202ba0 0x100202ba0 
0x100202bb4 0x100202bb4 0x100202bb4 0x100202bb4 0x100202bb4 
0x100202bc8 0x100202bc8 0x100202bc8 0x100202bc8 0x100202bc8 
0x100202bdc 0x100202bdc 0x100202bdc 0x100202bdc 0x100202bdc 
0x100202bf0 0x100202bf0 0x100202bf0 0x100202bf0 0x100202bf0 
Allocating array 1d, 1d style fails...
Allocating 1d array 2d style... success!?
Displaying allocated array.
13 13 13 13 13 
13 13 13 13 13 
13 13 13 13 13 
13 13 13 13 13 
13 13 13 13 13 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```